# Mysql: concatenation symbol inside Concat with conditional statement

Tags: mysql, sql

**Sql:**

```
concat(Discount,'% ',if(Net_Deferred=0,' Spot Cash',Net_Deferred, ' months deferral'))
```

**The issue:**

if(...Net_Deferred, ' months deferral'..

The **comma** that concatenate the 2 strings throws an error because if statement only works on 2 commas (true or false)

The result should look like this:

If(Net_Deferred=0) : **Spot Cash**

else : **24 months deferral**

*value 24 comes from* `Net_Deferred` *field*.

**Question:**
How to concatenate field inside concat with `if else` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `concat` again

```
IF(Net_Deferred = 0, " Spot Cash", CONCAT(Net_Deferred, " months deferral"))
```

Comment: Thanks.. I was thinking this also.. but is there any way to concatenate the 2 values other than a comma inside if statement? (I mean symbol)

Comment: @Boyd I only wrote the `if` part; you can still wrap my answer in `CONCAT(Discount, '%', IF(...`

Comment: yes I did already... I'm just curious if there is other concatenation symbol to use instead of adding concat inside concat. THank you